# Sum of a binomial relation confusion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, spherical-harmonics

I'm having trouble in understanding how to use the sum in the relation below:
$$
{}_sP_{jm}(\cos\theta) 
= \frac{(j+m)!}{\!\sqrt{(j+s)!(j-s)!}} 
\biggl(\!\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\biggr)^{\!2j} \,
\sum_{n}^{j-s} \binom{j-s}{n} \binom{j+s}{n-m+s} (-1)^{j-n-s} 
\biggl(\!\cot{\frac{\theta}{2}}\biggr)^{\!2n-m+s}\,,
$$
because when I try the ${}_\frac{1}{2}P_{\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}}$ the binomials become:
$$
\binom{1}{n} \binom{2}{n-1} 
= \frac{1}{n!(1-n)!} \frac{2!}{(n-1)!(3-n)!} 
$$
which is only possible for the values: $n=1$.

Does the sum run over only at the values of $n$ in which the expression is defined (positive arguments in the factorial)?

Is my representation of the binomials correct? I have seen it throughout many sources.

Comment: It looks like $n$ must be the dummy variable for the summation, but what is its initial value? You've written $\sum_n^{j-s}$ where one might expect something like $\sum_{n=0}^{j-s}$. Also, when the dummy variable takes successive integer values, and the upper limit is a non-integer $u$, this is usually interpreted as meaning $\lfloor u \rfloor$, much like C-type code "for (n = 0; n =< u; n++)"

Comment: the articles I am using just use (n), indeed (n=0) is supposed, this is another confusion

Comment: @MPW , since the (s,j,m) are half integers, the coeficients related to the binomial are always integers, so this problems never happen. (doi: 10.1098/rspa.1977.0187)

Comment: Can you cite the source articles so we can look, if possible?

Comment: Sure! Here is what I'm using but there are a lot more: "Breuer, Reinhard A., Michael P. Ryan, and Sergio Waller. "Some properties of spin-weighted spheroidal harmonics." Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. A. Mathematical and Physical Sciences 358.1692 (1977): 71-86."

Comment: the expression I showed above is proportional do the D-matrix of Wigner. In pg. 77 of "Varshalovich, Dmitriĭ Aleksandrovich, Anatolij Nikolaevič Moskalev, and Valerii Kel'manovich Khersonskii. Quantum theory of angular momentum. World scientific, 1988." the D-matrix is evaluated and there is this sentence :"In Eqs. (2)-(5) k runs over all integer values for which the factorial arguments are non-negative.". Do you agree?